# What do we call a lattice that does not have a sublattice the shape of the diamond $M_3$?

Tags: terminology, lattice-orders

Let $L$ denote a lattice. If no sublattice of $L$ is shaped like the [pentagon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aSmallest_nonmodular_lattice_1.svg) $N_5$, we call $L$ *modular*. Supposing furthermore that no sublattice of $L$ is shaped like the [diamond](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aDiamond_lattice.svg) $M_3$, we call $L$ *distributive*.

What do we call a lattice that does not have a sublattice the shape of the diamond $M_3$, but which might have a sublattice the shape of $N_5$? Furthermore, is there a nice "algebraic" characterization of this property, like there is for modularity and distributivity?

Comment: On [mathoverflow.se] - currently in HNQ: [Class of lattices that excludes $M_3$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/359113)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\mathbf K$ be the class of all lattices not containing $M_3$ (the $5$-element nondistributive modular lattice) as a sublattice; in other words, lattices in which every modular sublattice is distributive. It is easy to see that $\mathbf K$ can be characterized as the class of all lattices satisfying the following sentence $\varphi$:
$$\forall u\forall v\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc=u)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c=v)\rightarrow(u=v)]$$
or equivalently
$$\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c)\rightarrow(ab=a+b)]$$
or
$$\forall a\forall b\forall c[(ab=ac=bc)\wedge(a+b=a+c=b+c)\rightarrow(a=b)].$$

Inasmuch as $\varphi$ is a universal Horn sentence, it follows that $\mathbf K$ is closed under taking sublattices and direct products.

On the other hand, $\mathbf K$ can not be characterized by identities, and is not closed under taking homomorphic images. Bjarni Jónsson [Sublattices of a free lattice, Canad. J. Math. 13 (1961), 256-264, Lemma 2.6(i)] observed that, as a corollary of P. M. Whitman's work, elements $u,a,b,c$ of a free lattice satisfy the condition: if $u=ab=ac$, then $u=a(b+c)$. It follows that $M_3$ is not a sublattice of a free lattice, i.e, the class $\mathbf K$ contains all free lattices. Thus every lattice is a homomorphic image of a member of $\mathbf K$, and every identity which holds in all $M_3$-free lattices is a consequence of the lattice axioms. In view of this, there is not likely to be any "nicer" algebraic characterization of the $M_3$-free lattices than the one in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Great answer! I'm also interested in terminology for this property, if you know of any.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I never heard of it before. I didn't really answer your question, did I? You shouldn't have accepted my answer so fast. Feel free to unaccept it; maybe then somebody who knows lattice theory will come along and tell you what you want to know.

Comment: You answered the second part about a nice algebraic characterization very thoroughly, which is why I accepted it. Anyway, I'm going to have a look at Grätzer's Lattice Theory: Foundation later tomorrow, so perhaps I'll find its name there.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm also interested in terminology for this property, if you know of any.

There might be some relevant terminology in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-06251-8_20). (You can find preprints other places.)

The work includes an axiom 'RL1' Figure 1/page 10 that's a tighter form of @bof's φ. (To be precise, RL1 implies φ, but not v.v.)

```
∀a∀b∀c[ab + ac = a( (a + c)b + (a + b)c ) ]
```

(Each of the papers I look it wrt lattices seem to use their own idiosyncratic notation. I hope I translated that one correctly.)