# Distributive (sub-)lattice with a triangle 'tile'

Tags: lattice-orders

Following from [this Q+A](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4806677/156669), I have a family of lattices such that:

- They are not Distributive in general;
- They do not include any diamond sub-lattice M<sub>3</sub>;
- They do include pentagon sub-lattice N<sub>5</sub>;
- Specific sub-lattices are distributive -- Edit: in fact they seem to be Boolean Algebras; except with great difficulty to algebraically express each sub-lattice's least and greatest elements.

To specify those sub-lattices I use (Prover9 format):

```
x ^ R00 = y ^ R00 & y ^ R00 = z ^ R00 -> x v (y ^ z) = (x v y) ^ (x v z).
```

Edit: In this case, `x ^ R00` is the least element.

In which the RHS of the `->` is [the usual Distributivity constraint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice#Definition); the LHS constrains the three participating nodes.

Now every diagram I can find of Distributive (sub-)lattices shows a pattern of diamond tiles -- like the 'Young's lattice' shown on that wiki page. But Mace4 is generating a counter-example in which `x, y, z` meet the LHS constraint in the formula above, but they are the only three nodes in the sub-lattice -- IOW they form a triangle tile.

I've worked through applying that RHS formula, and they obey it whichever way round I assign `x, y, z`. But this isn't <s>Distributive</s> a Boolean algebra in the sense I want or expect.

What I'm getting is similar to the [wiki diagram "M<sub>3</sub> (right)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Non-dstrbtive_lattices-warning.png) (which is showing this isn't really an M<sub>3</sub> sub-lattice), specifically nodes `b, e, c`; but no dotty line `d...b` -- that is, `d ^ b = c = d ^ e`. Also no line `a--e` -- that is, `a, e` are not adjacent, `b v e = b`. In this case `d` is the specified element `R00`, so `b ^ d = e ^ d = c ^ d = c`.

I'm expecting there would be a fourth node (say `f`) between `b--c`, thus:

- Forming a diamond `b-f-c; b-e-c`; and
- a pentagon `a-d-c; a-b-f-c`.

I'm wanting a diamond tile, so that I can get a complement. Without an `f`, what is the complement of `e` within the sub-lattice `b-e-c`?

Edit: I see that for a ["sub-lattice (viewed as an interval) [that] is complemented"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complemented_lattice#Definition_and_basic_properties) there is a 'local' complement. Given three elements that I can establish belong to the same sub-lattice, can I express a 'local' least and greatest element from just those three?

Comment: Note to self: 'sectionally complemented lattice' might be relevant here https://planetmath.org/sectionallycomplementedlattice#:~:text=Dually%2C%20one%20defines%20a%20dually,L%E2%88%82%20is%20sectionally%20complemented. In which for any element `a` the 'local' least element is `a ^ R00`; the interval `[a ^ R00, a]` is sectionally complemented. Point "1. Every pair of elements have a difference." is exactly what I'm aiming for, even though the overall structure isn't a Boolean algebra.

Comment: The wiki diagram linked in the Q that "contains N5" (left), seems to show a triangle 'tile' `b-f-c`. Is the lattice overall Distributive? Click on it and see the comments below: (author) " - Own work". Sounds close to 'original research'.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as your edits hint, what you're aiming for is not merely a sub-lattice that's Distributive, but also a [Boolean algebra/lattice](https://planetmath.org/BooleanLattice). This requires not only Distributivity but also Complementation. Unfortunately, most of the materials for Complements assume the whole Lattice is Complemented, so example formulas use overall least and greatest elements `0, 1`. More explanation to follow, but first ...

**(Wire-)Framing the question: "triangle 'tile'"**

There is no such thing as a triangle tile within a lattice diagram. The "- own work" diagrams on that wikipage are just wrong. You can't select some arbitrary subset of elements and expect the same lattice structure to apply -- indeed the resulting elements might not form a lattice at all.

(Educationally it would help if other learning resources such as PlanetMath/Wolfram showed diagrams, not just formulas. There are a few other sites out there with diagrams -- mostly notes for undergraduate courses -- including even a few with apparently triangles. But I couldn't find explicit 'rules' for how to produce diagrams.)

Take the alleged triangle `b-f-c` of the ["contains N<sub>5</sub>" (left)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Non-dstrbtive_lattices-warning.png). The `b-f` segment shows `b ^ f = f`; the `f-c` segment shows `f ^ c = c`. Then necessarily `b ^ c = c` (by transitivity of `^`); but it is not the convention to show that as a separate line segment. Otherwise, you'd be drawing lines from lattice top `a` to every other element, and seem to get (for example) two triangles `a-b-f, a-c-f`.

You'd only get a segment `b-c` if element `f` was removed (as shown by the dotty lines `b...f, f...c`) -- but in that case there'd be no `f` to form a triangle.

So a line segment in the diagrams mean this is the shortest path between those elements/there's no other element in between.

**Answer: Boolean sub-lattice**

> - They [the family of lattices] are not Distributive in general;
> - They do include pentagon sub-lattice N5;

Then the lattices are not overall Boolean algebras.

> - Specific sub-lattices are distributive ... they seem to be Boolean Algebras;

Then they must be specified as *both* Distributive and Complemented. To specify the Complementation, you need to find a least (or dually, most) element within the sub-lattice to 'stand in for' `0` (or dually `1`).

> the 'local' least element is `a ^ R00`; [from your 'Note to self' comment]

Then yes ['sectionally complemented lattice'](https://planetmath.org/sectionallycomplementedlattice) is the applicable tool. (That is, if we take `L` from that definition to be a sub-lattice and `0` to be the "section"'s least element `a ^ R00`.) You can express complements using only sub-lattice bottom:

```
x ^ y = y & y ^ (x ^ R00) = (x ^ R00) -> exists z (z ^ y = x ^ R00 & z v y = x).
```

This says: for all elements `x`, for all `y` between `x` and its 'local' sub-lattice bottom `x ^ R00`, there exists `z` the complement of `y` within the sub-lattice interval `[x ^ R00, x]`.

IOW this treats `x` as 'local' lattice top; you don't need to find three distinct elements as with the Distributivity formula. And if any arbitrary element `x` of the sub-lattice is required to exhibit Complementarity, the whole sub-lattice must; and is therefore a Boolean sub-lattice.

With that formula included in the model you're working with, Mace4 doesn't generate non-Boolean counter-sub-lattices.

Comment: "Then necessarily `b ^ c = c`" so we don't get a triangle, but three-in-a-row. And that sub-lattice is Distributive but not Complemented (there's no complement for the middle node), so not a Boolean lattice.